# Is a sales clause prohibiting the buyer of exporting the goods outside of a zone legal?

Tags: european-union, france, is-x-legal

I bought some goods at my local Mercedes dealer in France, and I was stunned by a sales contract clause that reads :

> Le client s'engage : Export interdit hors UE/AELC/MC

Translation mine

> The client commits to : Export forbidden outside of EU/EFTA-EEA/Monaco

So I'm asking this question :

Is such clause, comming from a private company, legal and enforcable under French/EU law? I couldn't find anything related to that in my research

Looking at the [Access2Markets](https://trade.ec.europa.eu/access-to-markets/en/results?product=87087010&origin=FR&destination=AE) site of the EU, there no seeable restrictions between EU and non-EU for automotive parts (country dependent of course)

I know something similar is imposed by Toyota in Japan (for their Land Cruiser), but I have never seen that in French/EU Law.

Comment: I suggest it's not legal, yet would you really want to try to enforce anything? This is about a straight commercial contract between you and a retailer, which seems not to be worth legal action, either way.

Mercedes is one of many, if not most, marques that have tried to impose restrictions on their dealerships such that, for instance, they might not sell right-hand-drive cars to UK drivers at left-hand-drive, EU prices. 

That the EU greed with the would-be buying drivers didn't change the makers' views by one iota… so why should they re-act differently here?